# Forbid particular class compilation

Tags: c#, asp.net

Lets say I have 4 classes in my App_Code folder (A B C D) and I want to compile 3 of them (A B C), and leave D in .cs file. But C is referencing to D so I can't exclude D from App_Code folder.

How can I forbid particular class from compilation?

Comment: You cannot (short of moving D to a separate assembly and of course compiling it there), otherwise what code is the compiler supposed to generate for class C? Also, why on earth would you want to do this in the first place?

Comment: D is the class used to generate customizable ASP.NET controls, HTML codes for objects and other customizable tools. I wanted to compile all classes except this (thought it would be compiled on request, and would be modifiable) but as you said it really makes no sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick to solve this is instead of having classes `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D` all in your Web app you split it in to two projects. One DLL where you have classes `A`, `B`, and `C`, and interface `ID` and one Web App with the class `D` and has the DLL project as a referenced assembly.

You just change your references in `C` to the class `D` to the interface `ID` and compile the assembly. In your Web App and have `D` in it implement the `ID` interface defined in the referenced assembly.

Doing that will let you have the `D` class still be modifiable while having `A`, `B`, and `C` all be compiled.